# How to remove an equal item from the cart without deleting an equal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made e-commerce with a cart for activity using context API, but, when I am going to remove an item from the cart and I have two of them but when I remove one, I remove the other one. How to avoid it?

Inside my providers, this is my catalogue:

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react"

export const CatalogueContext = createContext([])

export const CatalogueProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [catalogue, setCatalogue] = useState([
        {id: 1, name: "Affogato", price: 10, img: affogato,},
        {id: 2, name: "Café preto", price: 10, img: black,},
        {id: 3, name: "Capuccino", price: 10, img: cappuccino,},
        {id: 4, name: "Dalgona", price: 10, img: dalgona,},
        {id: 5, name: "Doppio", price: 10, img: doppio,},
        {id: 6, name: "Expresso", price: 10, img: expresso,},
        {id: 7, name: "Galão", price: 10, img: galao,},
        {id: 8, name: "Irlandês", price: 10, img: irish},
        {id: 9, name: "Latte", price: 10, img: latte,},
        {id: 10, name: "Mocha", price: 10, img: mocha,}
    ])
    return (
        <CatalogueContext.Provider value={{ catalogue }} >
            {children}
        </CatalogueContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

This is my cart:

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const CartContext = createContext([])

export const CartProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [cart, setCart] = useState([])

    const addToCart = (item) => {
        setCart([...cart, item])
    }

    const removeFromCart = (item) => {
        const newCart = cart.filter((itemOnCart) => itemOnCart.id !== item.id)
        setCart(newCart)
    }
    return (
        <CartContext.Provider value={{ cart, addToCart, removeFromCart}} >
            {children}
        </CartContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use property for store a count of items in cart.
For example:
When user add first item you add it in array
When user try to add the same item, you need to update count for 1

Method `map` will help you

Same logic for removing. When user removes any item, you will find it in array and decrement counter. When counter will equal 0 - remove it from array

Method `find` will help you with whis